# Unable Convert UTC into Local Time on Android

Tags: java, android

I have a date in UTC '2022-04-09 11:16:32' i want to convert it to IST it shouldbe  '2022-04-09 04:46:32'
in my code i'm using

```
String date = dataItem.getTime().replaceAll("-","/");
        try {
            DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            Date d = utcFormat.parse(date);

            DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));


            holder.date.setText(pstFormat.format(d));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it prints 2022/04/09 10:16:32 whis is not the actual time.
please help me.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my desktop Java 17 I get `2022/04/09 16:46:32`.

Comment: What makes you consider `2022-04-09 04:46:32` right? Did you mean 04:46:32 PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2022-04-09 11:16:32"
    .replace( " " , "T" )  
)
.atOffset(
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
.atZoneSameInstant(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )
)
.format(
   DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
)
.replace( "T" , " " )
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/HdqND0).

> 2022-04-09 16:46:32

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date` after altering the string to comply with ISO 8601 standard.

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse your input as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
String input = "2022-04-09 11:16:32".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Apparently you are certain that the supplied date-with-time string was intended to be a moment in UTC, having an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

So apply an offset of zero, defined as a constant, to produce a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Next you want to adjust from UTC into a particular time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. The result represents the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but with a date and time as seen in that time zone.

There is no such time zone as `IST`. Nor `CST`, `PDT`, etc. These 2-4 character pseudo-zones are not real time zones. They are not standardized, and are not even unique! These are appropriate only for presentation to users, never for data exchange or data storage. Real time zones have name in format of `Continent/Region`.

By `IST` you might have meant `Europe/Dublin` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

To generate your desired text, define your own custom formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter`. Or use a predefined formatter for ISO 8601, and remove the `T`.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "IST" is not in an available timezone id, you can check the list with: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().
You can try with "Asia/Kolkata" instead.

```
        pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
```